# not getting tab view when we press back

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

hii every one

i have created a test project with tab view controller, on click of a tab it will goto that coresponding screen(say screen A) when i click back button in screen A it will come back to main page but with out tabView,
following is may code for back button where DataEntry is a class name to where i am navigating

```
DataEntry *avController;
UINavigationController *addNavigationController;


if(avController == nil)
        avController = [[DataEntry alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    if(addNavigationController == nil)
        addNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:avController];
    //avController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addNavigationController animated:YES];
```

insted of the above code if i use following code

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

it will work fine & ill get back to main page with tabs , but it wont run the updated code which is in the viewDidLoad  so i need to navigate to the  main page insted of using dismissModalViewController

can any one tell me how can i get tabView when i navigate to the main page with out using dismissModalViewController

Comment: I think part of your question is missing. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not correct:

`[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:addNavigationController animated:YES];`

(this is not what you mean to have: it will present a modal view, when you dismiss it, it will uncover what was below, i.e. your tab)

you should use `pushViewController` to show your `avController` so that the back button is activated and so on.

look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361852/uinavigationcontroller-push-views).

Comment: i have tried this but its crashing         crash log:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: you should not push your `addNavigationController` navigation controller: you already have one. you should push your `avController`... or else, what are you exactly trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling a little to understand your problem, but viewDidLoad only runs when the view loads: not when you come back to screen A : its still loaded then. To run code each time screen A is displayed, take a look at viewWillAppear / viewDidAppear http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I tend to create tabs programatically rather than using the IB: its clearer whats going on. Take a look at this answer to show how I do it.
[UITabBar with UINavigationController in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810385/uitabbar-with-uinavigationcontroller-in-code/2812647#2812647)